# five leasing company picklist fields on account object, need to crate chart group by leasing Companies

Tags: custom-report-type

I am reaching out with a query regarding displaying leasing companies' information in a  chart grouped by picklist values.  Account Object contains data pertaining to five leasing company picklist fields[image], as illustrated in the attached image.

The challenge lies in presenting the data in a single pie chart as the standard report functionality seems insufficient for this purpose. Despite efforts, it appears difficult to encompass all five leasing companies' information within one  chart using the standard reporting tools.

Could you kindly provide guidance on how we can achieve this requirement effectively?

Your assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.